# How to test correctness of concurrent requests with Karate?

Tags: rest, karate, web-api-testing

I'm using Karate, and I need to prove than an API is (im)properly working when receiving certain concurrent requests, so I'd need to perform the following **sequential** steps:

- *SETUP*: Perform some request to create some shared resource in the backend (a `Scenario`? requests in the `Background` section?)
- *TEST*:

  - Perform several requests in parallel somehow modifying that shared resource (a group of `Scenario`s in a feature, or maybe a data driven `Scenario Outline` with `Example`s run in parallel?)
  - Check that the shared resource has the expected data after all the concurrent requests have finished (another `Scenario`?)
- (possibly)*TEAR DOWN*: Remove the shared resource and any other resources created by the concurrent requests

Can you do this with Karate? How? If not, what other tool would you recommend to do this?

Comment: please look at `karate-gatling`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling

Comment: I already came across that, but from what I read in its documentation it wasn't clear to me if this could be done. I'll re-check it. Thanks a lot!